# What is the exact C# classes that matched with the below json? Nested two json objects have the same name problem

Tags: c#, json

Below json and C# class does not match because there are two json objects named same "Event". I am getting null from the second "Event" object. I could not find the matched C# class. What am I doing wrong?

```
{
    "Sequence": 1802487,
    "BusinessDate": "2020-05-17T00:00:00.0000000",
    "Event": {
        "Event": {
            "@RegId": "2269"
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the C# classes that I am using for deserializing. my c# class is below but I am getting null fro RegId in the second Event object

```
public class Root
    {
        public long Sequence { get; set; }
        public DateTime BusinessDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Event")]
        public Event1 Event { get; set; }
    }

public class Event1
    {
        [JsonProperty("Event")]
        public Event Event { get; set; }
    }

public class Event
    {
        [JsonProperty("@RegId")]
        public string RegId { get; set; }        
    }
```

Comment: I can't reproduce a problem, Json.NET deserializes that JSON into your model correctly, including populating `RegId` correctly, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/OXIqts.  Please provide a [mcve] for us to help you. Are you sure you are really using [tag:json.net] and not some other serializer such as [tag:system.text.json]?  The attribute `[JsonProperty("@RegId")]`  is from Json.NET which is why I assume you are using it.

Comment: The names of the Event and Event1 classes have no impact on how Json.net will deserialize the json in question, only the property names and the names in the attributes are relevant.

Comment: Yes you are right, I tried to deserialize by using Newtonsoft.JsonConvert and it worked fine. I am working on RavenDB and deserializing is done by it automatically. So I figured out that there is a problem with RavenDB deserializing process. Thank you for your help.